# Does Google Drive API search responds not only files/folder metadata but also the matched content w.r.t query in the search response?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

```
response = DRIVE.files().list(q="fullText contains 'what is python?',spaces='drive',fields='*',pageToken=page_token).execute()
```

from the above sample Python code,what extra param that I can pass or extract to get the files with the matched content as well with them?

Example response(current)

> {'kind': 'drive#file', 'id': '1acVspMMcliVE8M6WzNL14sdvXYT-dScw', 'name': '4590764611082297754.txt', 'mimeType': 'text/plain',.....}

So can this json response can also include the matched content from the query and also the score in any form.
Please let me know if this feature is available or can be coded/extracted somehow

Thanks

Comment: It depends, it seems that content in Google Documents (Docs, Sheets, etc.) can be searched with that, but non-Google Documents cannot. What kind of file you want to search for?

Answer (score 1):

The [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-shareddrives) parameter for file.list method allows you to search for things like files with a specific title, or file type

The google drive api is just a file storage system it does not have the power to open a file and see what it contains.  There is no method for searching the contents of a file.